# While appending the query string Error Summary HTTP Error 403.0 - ModSecurity Action error comes

Tags: asp.net

I am working in web application as soon as I append query string to 
something.com/Result.aspx?type=5&city=Kanpur&refine=/or/Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID=19/and/(SELECT/CASE/WHEN/ISNUMERIC(value_text)/=/1/THEN/CAST(value_text/AS/INT)/ELSE/-1/END)/between/0/and/100

It gives me this error
HTTP Error 403.0 - ModSecurity Action
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
While this url is working fine in local host 
What I am doing wrong kindly help.

Comment: Do you really allow SQL in your query string? Looks like the security module is functioning exactly as expected.

Comment: @codecaster yes I m how can I overcome this security module.